# StateFlow.value should not be called within composition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I downloaded Android Studio Bumblebee beta today and noticed a new warning:

"StateFlow.value should not be called within composition"

Why shouldn't we call StateFlow.value within composition?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because in composition you should be listening to events, not just reading the current one. If you read only the current one then your view won't get recomposed after the value is changed.

I mean - maybe there is a valid use case for that, but i never encountered one. I guess the warning you saw is just to warn users that they are trying to do something they probably don't want to

Comment: exactly with StateFlow.value you just reading the current value. To get updates use the collectAsState() method as in @Cabezas code example

Comment: in some cases  we just need get the current value of specific stateflow when other stateflows trigger recomposition, so that's why we don't need to collect the first stateflow if other stateflows triggered recomposition already

Comment: @user924 Well, sure, but that does not seem like a good practise in the first place. Being in sync with only one of the sources..

Comment: @Jakoss for example `if` condition, syncs to one state in the condition, to just enter a specific block of logic where you just get `StateFlow.value`

Comment: @user924 still looks weird to me. Even in if condition i'd always want to be in sync of the flow

Comment: There is surprisingly good documentation here https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/StateFlowValueCalledInComposition.md.html

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I added `.collectAsState()` like this

```
@Composable
fun yourScreen() {
    val state = viewModel.viewState.collectAsState()
    when (state.value) {
        // your code
    } 
}
```

Comment: That is how I do it now, and I don't see the warnings anymore